# User defined script timed out. Timeout is set to 30.0 s

Tags: time-series, tableau-api, tabpy

Hi I an integrating my python code for time series forecasting with tableau using tabpy. While executing the code as calculated field it giving this erro: "User defined script timed out. Timeout is set to 30.0 s.". I have increased timeout in default.config already. Please suggest some sulution.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the value of **TABPY_EVALUATE_TIMEOUT** is hard coded somewhere in the python code used for tabpy server.

check in the **tabpy\tabpy_server\app\app.py** file, if you find out any hard coded value there just change the number to your required value or else check in other python files in the folder for the hard coded value and change it.

Incase you didn't find that path check in the log file of the tabpy, you will get to know that path.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/tableau/TabPy/blob/master/docs/server-config.md) you can set this parameter in your configuration file and when you launch Tabpy from the command line, just specify *absolute* to your configuration file like this: `tabpy --config=absolute/path/to/your/config/file.conf`

You can find a configuration file example under the link above. The parameter which you need to set is TABPY_EVALUATE_TIMEOUT, so in your case configuration file could look like this(if you want to extend timeout time to 2 minutes, for example):

```
[TabPy]
TABPY_EVALUATE_TIMEOUT = 120
```

All other parameters will be taken from default configuration file.